# Determine relationship between vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Using the product i would like to understand  if it is possible to determine relationship between two vectors,let us consider the following problem:

> Vectors $u$ and $v$ have length $1$. Which of the assumptions $(a)-(g)$ below imply that vectors $u$ and $v$ are: $$\begin{array}{c|c}
>   \text{i} & \text{prependicular} \\
>   \hline
>   \text{ii} & \text{parallel and pointing in the same direction} \\
>   \hline
>   \text{iii} & \text{parallel and pointing in the opposite direction} \\
>   \hline
>   \text{iv} & \text{parallel and no information about directions}
>  \end{array}$$  $$\text{(a) } u \cdot v = -1$$ $$\text{(b) } u \cdot v = 1$$ $$\text{(c) } |u \cdot v| = 1$$ $$\text{(d) } |u \cdot v| = 0$$ $$\text{(e) } u \cdot v = 0$$

Sure one thing we can easily say that if  dot product  of two vector is zero,they are perpendicular (orthogonal),parallel and pointing in the same  direction,for example if we multiply  vector by some scalar ,we get parallel and same  direction vector,maybe  product of them  should be positive?if  opposite direction,maybe their   product is $-1$ ?about $(iv)$  maybe  if  absolute value of product is $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf u. \mathbf v=|\mathbf u||\mathbf v|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors. So If they are parallel and pointing to the same direction then $\mathbf u. \mathbf v=1$, parallel and pointing to the opposite direction then $\mathbf u. \mathbf v=-1$, parallel and no information about the direction $|\mathbf u. \mathbf v|=1$.

Comment: so my  guess was correct,what about $d$

Comment: With the difference that the positive vector product is not enough for being parallel.

Comment: ok but what about choice $d$?

Comment: $|\mathbf u. \mathbf v|=0$ is same as $\mathbf u. \mathbf v=0$ which means that vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: so this   statement  $|u,v|=1$ means that it's product  could be as positive as well as  negative like,so it  means undefined

Comment: not in this case. We do not know whether it is negative or positive but we do know that it is at its maximum possible value here. This means that the angle between vectors is either $0$ or $\pi$.